# probability on Poisson process

Tags: probability, poisson-process

Three customers A, B, and C, simultaneously arrive at a bank with two tellers on duty. The two tellers were idle when the three customers arrived, and A goes directly to one teller, B goes to the other teller, and C waits until either A or B leaves before she can begin receiving service. If the service times provided by the tellers are exponentially distributed with a mean of 4 minutes, what is the probability that customer A is still in the bank after the other two customers leave

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Denoting the service times by $A,B,C$ you are asked to find:$$\Pr(A>B+C)=\Pr(A>B)\Pr(A-B>C\mid A>B)$$
Use symmetry to find the first factor. Exponential distribution is [memoryless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Memorylessness) and this fact (again together with symmetry) can be used to find the second factor.

Other route is working out:$$\Pr(A>B+C)=\int\Pr(A>b+c)f_B(b)f_C(c)dbdc$$